# Guess sound game, ios

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, audio

I want to make an easy "game". When player start the game, it plays sound (for example dog bark) and player has to guess to which animal (musical instrument..) the sound belongs to.

I dont know how to make the "logic" of this program - how to connect image with its sound. 
I was thinking about something like this:

if app plays sound1 then right image is image1, if plays sound2 then right image is image2...but what if I have 100 images?

It is not possible doing it like this. Do you have any ideas please?

Answer (score 3):

You will have to map the sound files with the images.
One way, as you suggested would be to prefix them with an ID, for example:

- 001_img.png - 001_sound.mp3
- 002_img.png - 002_sound.mp3
- 003_img.png - 003_sound.mp3
- 004_img.png - 004_sound.mp3
- 005_img.png - 005_sound.mp3

And use a code snippet below to generate the filenames:

```
for (int assetIndex = 0; assetIndex < 6; assetIndex++)
{
    NSString *imageFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03i_img.png", assetIndex + 1];
    NSString *soundFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%03i_sound.mp3", assetIndex + 1];
}
```